# UIBarButtonItem -appereanceWhenContainedIn: and custom UINavigationBar subclass

Tags: uikit, ios6, ios

I'm using the new API in `UINavigationController` to use a custom `UINavigationBar`:

```
- (id)initWithNavigationBarClass:(Class)navigationBarClass toolbarClass:(Class)toolbarClass.
```

passing `[MyNavigationBar class]`.

Then I'm doing:

```
[UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn:[MyNavigationBar class], nil];
```

To customize `UIBarButtonItems` that are inside a `MyNavigationBar` and this is styling all bar button items in navigation controller with a standard `UINavigationBar`.

Has anyone managed to get this working somehow? Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: I'm just going by the docs here, haven't actually tried this... But I'm intrigued. It appears that `MyNavigationBar` needs to implement the `UIAppearanceContainer` protocol so it can be used in the `-appearanceWhenContainedIn:` call, or an exception will be thrown. So you are probably implementing it, but how exactly? The docs on this are a bit sparse to say the least.

Comment: The `UIAppearanceContainer` protocol is a weird one: it doesn't contain any methods :) It's kind of just a flag. In any case, `MyNavigationBar` inherits from `UINavigationBar`, which already conforms to the protocol...